# Reset custom Mail UserHeaders settings in Terminal

Tags: terminal, email

How do I reset the following command?

```
defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Reply-To" = "reply-to@address"; }'
```

I had to use this workaround for a problem with the hosting provider that used the same IP address for all outgoing mail. Because of that, my mails kept ending up in Junk mailboxes. That problem is solved now. So how do I reset this command?

Answer (score 2):

To remove all customisations to `UserHeaders`, use the `delete` verb in your `defaults` command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.mail UserHeaders
```

To replace the single `Reply-To` value with a blank entry, use:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Reply-To" = ""; }'
```

The [defaults manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) explains other available verbs.